# HTTPServletRequest getting requested URL

Tags: servlets

I am using servlets to allow clients to do CRUD Operations on a list. However I have one servlet, but it's possible to have multiple URL's get to this servlet because I have a wildcard character in the URL-Pattern.

http://localhost:8080/WebServiceDesignStyles3ProjectServer/SpyListCollection

This is the generic way to send a request to the servlet. However, for certain operations

http://localhost:8080/WebServiceDesignStyles3ProjectServer/SpyListCollection/{name}

Is a valid way to send a request to the servlet. I need to be able to get the last portion of that URL. It was told that I should be using getHeader("Accept") to be retrieving that. I've had success using getRequestURI(), but I was hoping someone could provide an example using getHeader(). Or at least an explanation describing the differences of the two.

Thank you for your time,
Kirie

Answer (score 0):

You could split the request path by the separator(/) and check the last part.

```
String reqURI = req.getRequestURI();
String[] parts = reqURI.split("/");
if (parts[parts.length - 1].equals("SpyListCollection") {
    //Generic operation
} else {
    String operation = parts[parts.length - 1];
}
```